# Grabbing nth line from multiple text files to rename matching pdf file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, text, command-line

I am trying to create a batch script to process upwards of 50 text files. There are PDFs with matching file names to the text files. I am trying to grab the 12th line from a text file and rename its corresponding PDF file to the contents of the entire 12th line. So far, I have been able to do this by referencing a specific file:

> FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n .* "File1.txt"') DO (
>           IF "%%A" equ "12" ren "File1.pdf" "%%B.pdf"
>   )

I'm having trouble taking that line and having it parse through multiple files. The files are also sitting in a directory path that has spaces. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.txt") DO IF EXIST "%%~dpna.pdf" (
 SET unchanged=Y
 FOR /f "usebackqskip=11delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF DEFINED unchanged (
  ECHO(REN "%%~dpna.pdf" "%%b.pdf"
  SET "unchanged="
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
pushd "your folder with spaces in name"
for /f "eol=: tokens=1,3 delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /n "^" *.txt ^|findstr "^[^:]*:12:"'
) do if exist "%%~nA.pdf" ren "%%~nA.pdf" "%%B"
popd
```

The first FINDSTR lists the content of all .TXT files. Each line of output has the format

```
fileName:lineNumber:content
```

The second FINDSTR preserves only the 12th line of each file.

The FOR /F parses the result, extracting the text file name before the first colon, and the content (new file name) after the second colon. Colons are not valid in file names, so I am assuming the content never has a colon in it.

Finally the DO section verifies the PDF exists, and then renames it.

Comment: Just an idle comment that in this case `findstr "^[^:]*:12:"` can simply be `findstr ":12:"` as neither the filename or the text to rename a file can contain a `:`

Comment: @foxidrive - I don't think that is a safe assumption. We don't know what lines 1-11 look like, nor lines 13 and above. But thanks for fixing the pipe.

Comment: No worries.  I see now what you are protecting against with other lines containing `:12:`